Detecting if an assembly contains Razor pages or components
I have a plugin architecture where I use the app.MapRazorComponents<MyApp>().AddAdditionalAssemblies() method to add the plugin assemblies to Razor page mapping.
The plugins are not guaranteed to include any pages so I only want to add assemblies that has files with the @page directive.
I've done some debugging to find that the classes generated for the .razor files have the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute] set on them, so I guess the @page directive is translated to a [Route] attribute.
The [Route] attribute, however, can also be used on Controllers, which are added differently (.MapControllers()), so only using this attribute as a marker is not enough.
I could probably exclude types that also has the [ApiController] attribute, or add checks for even more attributes (or inheritances), but I feel this can quickly get out of hand.
This is in .NET 8 using the Blazor Web App template with Server render mode.
Is there a way to check if an assembly contains any .razor files (be it pages or components), or alternatively check if an assembly is a "Razor Class Library" or not just a "Class Library"?

When you say "Razor Page", do you in fact mean Razor components that have an @page directive? They are not the same thing. Razor Pages are added using .AddRazorPages() and .MapRazorPages() whereas Razor components implement ComponentBase.

@MikeBrind I could probably have been more specific. This is actually a Blazor Web App, but it seems that Blazor app and Razor pages are becoming more and more intertwined. The template for a new Blazor Web App contains pages served both as regular razor pages, as well as Blazor pages/components.

AddAdditionalAssemblies will handle your needs, what else do you need to manually check them?

@shingo I don't want to add assemblies that don't have any pages in them so that .NET doesn't have to search through irrelevant assemblies when looking for a page.

This is the same method used to detect razor pages as the AddAdditionalAssemblies method.
static bool ContainsRazorPagesOrComponents(Assembly assembly)
{
    var exported = assembly.GetExportedTypes();

    for (var i = 0; i < exported.Length; i++)
    {
        var candidate = exported[i];
        if (candidate.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IComponent)))
        {
            if (candidate.GetCustomAttributes<RouteAttribute>() is { } routes &&
                routes.Any())
            {          
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}


Thank you! The IComponent inheritance was what I needed.
